# SQL Matching Float with Nvarchar(50) successfully in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

I have a field of type **nVarchar(50)** in **TABLEA**, that I would like to match against another field in another table, **TABLEB** with type **float**, in a table join relationship. How can I successfully match these two fields in my join?

```
left join UPS u on  RTRIM( LTRIM(Str(u.Float_Field,10, 10)))  = e.NVarchar_Field
```

Comment: Why? Even if you succeed, it's going to be a mess. Please stop trying now.

Answer (score 0):

I agree on that it is a bad idea but if you need this for purpose, here is an idea:

You can try `CAST(... as nchar(10))` on the float.

[Like here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc546/3)

Comment: I switched it to nvarchar(50). Will that help? Essentially, I would like to change the type on the NVarchar(50) column in the Table to Float but not sure how to do that. So if you are able to help me with information on how to, in table design, change from Varchar to Float, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to rename the column and make the new column with float. And then you can try to make an update on the new column based on the old, and then drop the old.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take two things into consideration:

1. Internal representation of float may cause "tiny" differences between two numbers that seems equal at first (except comparing zero to zero maybe). Take 1.9999999999 and 2.0 as examples.
2. String representation of floats can also differ as `14.55` is mathematically equal to `1.455E2` but string are presented quite differently (contain different characters).

So the only thing you can actually compare is **ranges**. You can either compare ranges of floats (imho better) or ranges of strings (provided that you make sure that floats are formatted identically on both sides: same number of digits after decimal point, no exponential notation etc.).

What I mean is that you need to let SQL parse your string down to float (using `CONVERT` for example) and then check whether the **difference** between numbers is small enough that you can consider them equal. For example `ABS(a - b) < 0.0000001`.